# CI Triggers on Pipelines in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines

Im having real issues with a pipeline everytime someone commits or pushes something to a branch on our repo, the pipeline triggers, in following the Microsoft Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers

Putting in Exclude features on every branch that we have the pipeline will still run when someone does a commit to a local branch even if I have wild carded the branch.

Has anyone been able to get this to work, that the pipeline should only run when there is a commit to Master only and nothing else.

Here is my Code:

```html
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    exclude:
    - CICV/*
    - An/*
    - Prod/*
    - Test/*
    - Dev/*
    - dev/*
    - IN/*
    - id/*
    - St/*
    - tr/*
      
    
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  demands: npm

variables: 
  System.Debug: false
  azureSubscription: 'RunPipelinesInProd'
  RG: 'VALUE'
  Location: UK South 
  containername: 'private'
  appconnectionname: 'RunPipelinesInProd'

jobs:

- job: job1
  displayName: Create And Publish Artifact
  pool:
    vmImage: vs2017-win2016
  steps:
 
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: Use .Net Core 3.1.x SDK
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      version: '3.1.x'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: dotnet restore
    inputs:
      command: restore
      projects: 'Website.csproj'

  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'npm install'
    inputs:
      workingDir: ClientApp
      verbose: false   
  
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'npm run build'
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      workingDir: ClientApp
      customCommand: 'build'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: dotnet build
    inputs:
      projects: 'Website.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration Release'
  
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: dotnet Test
    inputs:
     command: test
     projects: 'UnitTests/UnitTests.csproj'
     arguments: '--configuration Release'
      
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: dotnet publish
    inputs:
      command: publish
      projects: 'Website.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration Release --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      zipAfterPublish: true
      modifyOutputPath: false
      
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: Publish Pipeline Artifact
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifact: 'Website'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- job: job2
  displayName: Create Web App 
  dependsOn: job1   
  steps:

 # Download Artifact File
  - download: none
  - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
    displayName: 'Download Build Artifacts'
    inputs:
      patterns: '**/*.zip'
      path: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

  # deploy to Azure Web App 
  - task: AzureWebApp@1
    displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: nsclassroom-dgyn27h2dfoyo'
    inputs:
      package: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip 
      azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
      ConnectedServiceName: $(appconnectionname)
      appName: 'VALUE'
      ResourceGroupName: $(RG)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in the end, I ended up down the route of managing through the Azure Dev Ops Portal.

It seems that if you try to use YAML to manage this it just doesn't work, but if you do it through the web interface as outlined in Answer 2, then the behaviour is as expected. I think that the Microsoft YAML part is broken for this but I already have three issues open with Microsoft I don't wish to add another one to follow and tag.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a complex trigger like the one you outlined to trigger the pipeline on pushes to master. The following simple trigger configuration should work:

```
trigger:
  - master
```

If there's anything in the `include` section, then only pushes to these branches trigger the build. If you specify both `include` and `exclude` sections, then it will try to exclude some subset from the `include` set - just like in the sample from the docs:

```
# specific branch build
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
    exclude:
    - releases/old*
```

If the pipeline is still triggered by the push to some other branch, then it must be something else that triggers it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @yan-sklyraneko in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67179261/7360635) your trigger configuration should be as simple as

```
trigger:
 - master
```

However the trigger in your YAML file can be overridden in the GUI.  Navigate to your pipeline and click `Edit` then click the ellipses as shown below and select `Triggers`

[image]

On that screen check that the `Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here` box is unticked

[image]